# Create Event Log Source as part of installation - windows forms app, vs deployment project

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a vb.net windows form app that I am deploying as using the visual studio deployment project.  The app needs to write event logs to the application log in the event viewer.  For reasons explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/00a043ae-9ea1-4a55-8b7c-d088a4b08f09/) I need to create the event source during the installation process.  Something like this to run as part of the installer

```
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists(My.Application.Info.ProductName) Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(My.Application.Info.ProductName, "Application")
        End If
```

That code needs to be run during the installer with elevated privileges.  So my questions are:

1. How do I execute that code above as part of the installer?
2. How do I get the installer to do the UAC prompt to allow that code to run as part of the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an empty registry key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MY_CUSTOM_SOURCE_NAME_HERE` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the approach in EventLogInstaller Class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller(v=vs.90).aspx (Admin permissions required during installation)

May also be interested in using ProjectInstaller class as described in Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Sorry - just saw your note re Windows Forms. Above only good for Windows Service